# Android Service Memory Usage

Tags: android, memory, service

I have an Android app with a running service.

When I look in the "Running Apps" menu in Android settings, I see that my app memory usage is 
between 9-16MB .

I used DDMS Allocation Tracker to see where this is coming from, but all of the objects were less than 500 bytes.

Does it make sense? Any other ways to track my app's memory usage?

Also, I have an SQLite database opened as long as the service is running. Is that an impact on memory as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Did this got solved now? How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make sense?

It neither makes sense nor doesn't make sense. You can get to "9-16MB" by increments of 500 as easily as you can get there by increments of 5000. Also, AFAIK that allocation tracker does not track everything (e.g., bitmaps on pre-3.0 environments).

> Any other ways to track my app's memory usage?

Dump your heap (e.g., using the Dump HPROF File toolbar button in DDMS) and examine the results with the MAT plugin for Eclipse. There was a presentation on this at the 2011 Google I|O conference -- [the YouTube video is online](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk). You can use this to track memory leaks.

> Is that an impact on memory as well?

Some, I'm sure.

Another issue is actually the service itself. Your objective should be to have that service in memory as little as possible, and only while it is actively delivering continuous value to the user. Ideally, your service is destroyed ~99% of the time.